# Verify the checkbox is checked in Cypress

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress

I want to verify the checkbox is checked. This is the HTML for the checkbox

[image]

the js for it:

```
    localShopClerkcheckbox(){
        return cy.get("[name='isLocalClerk']")
        //return cy.get(':nth-child(4) > .dx-box-flex > :nth-child(2) > .dx-item-content > .dx-last-col > .dx-field-item-content > .dx-show-invalid-badge > .dx-checkbox-container > .dx-checkbox-icon')
    }
```

Then on step definition:

```
Then("I see the Local Shop clerk is selected",() =>{
    backofficeCreateDeleteClerkPage.localShopClerkcheckbox().should('have.attr','aria-checked',true)

})
```

strangely Cypress shows that the **expected value was true but the value was true**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change `true` to `'true'`. The true is a string.

```js
backofficeCreateDeleteClerkPage
  .localShopClerkcheckbox()
  .should('have.attr', 'aria-checked', 'true')
```

Answer (score 4):

You can verify a checkbox is checked using [state assertions](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/assertions#State).

**Sample HTML Checkbox**

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" name="myCheckbox" checked="" data-cy="myCheckbox">
```

**Assert that a checkbox is checked**

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="myCheckbox"]').should('be.checked')
```

**Assert that a checkbox is not checked**

```js
cy.get('[data-cy="myCheckbox"]').should('not.be.checked');
```

**Example**

```js
backofficeCreateDeleteClerkPage
  .localShopClerkcheckbox()
  .should('be.checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cy.GetByType('checkbox').should('not.be.checked')
 cy.GetByType('checkbox').should('be.checked')
```